# What Force is acting here?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, free-body-diagram

[image]

A Smooth Disc with a grove is rotated with constant angular velocity, about its center

A block is placed in the grove.

What force is acting on the block here to "throw" the block outside the grove, if we look at it from the ground frame?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A mass in a rotating tube](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/231417/)

Answer (score 0):

> What force is acting on the block here to "throw" the block outside
> the grove, if we look at it from the ground frame?

There is no such force, and no such force is necessary. There is no centripetal force, so the block cannot be kept at a constant distance from the center of the disk.

Comment: There is no centripetal force. But without any force it couldn't move, nor could the disc

Comment: @planetmaker : there is a tangential force acting on the block, but not "a force to throw the block outside the groove".

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a force pushing it outward when you are looking at it from the ground frame, it is the tendency for the block to keep moving combined with the disc actually turning.

It is the same as when you go around a corner in a car and you feel like you are being pushed to one side of the car; from the ground frame you know there isn't a force pushing you outward, it is just your tendency to keep moving combined with the car actually turning the corner.